# Iteration Error with TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not callable

Tags: python, syntax, iteration

QUESTION:
***I am finding issues with the syntax of the code, in particular the for loop which i use to loop through the external file.***

*My program is a dice game which is supposed to register users, and the allow them to login to the game afterwards. In the end it must access the external file, which has previously been used to store the winner name (keep in mind the authorised names have a separate file), and loops through it and outputs the top 5 winners names and scores to the shell*

**I used a for loop to loop through the file and append it to an array called '*Top 5 Winners*' however I seem to struggle with the syntax of the code as I am quite new Python.**

The code that accesses the file.

```
with open("Top 5 Winners.txt","r") as db:
    top5Winners=[]

    for i in db(0,len([db])):

        top5Winners.append(line)

    top5Winners.sort()
    top5Winners.reverse() 
    for i in range(5):
        print(top5Winners[i])
```

Error Code:

```
for i in db(0,len([db])):
```

*The len() part of the code is the issue*

NOTE:
I also wouldn't mind any tips as to how i make this bit of code more efficient so i can apply it in my later projects.

Comment: please fix your indentation. as it stands, this code throws a SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation isn't as it should be. You indeed opened a file and made it readable, but after that you didn't do anything with it. See the following example:

```
with open(file, 'r') as db:
    #code with file (db)
#rest of the code
```

So you can combine with your code like this:

```
top5winners = []                                  #Make a list variable
with open("Top 5 Winners.txt","r") as db:         #Open your file
    for i in db:                                  #Loop trough contents of file
        top5winners.append(i)                     #Append iterable to list
top5winners.sort(reverse=True)                    #Sort list and use reverse option
for i in range(0, 5):                             #Loop trough range
    print(top5winners[i])                         #Print items from list
```

Please note that StackOverflow is intended for help with specific cases, not a site to ask others to write a piece of code.

Sincerly, Chris Fowl.

Comment: How does the .append[i] work? I thought the index was just a number for a specific iteration, does that mean anything in the db is assigned to the index? It worked for me however i cant grasp as to why that works.

Comment: Above the statement I made a loop. Each time the loop loops, it gets one line from your file. That line gets appended to a list, as a string. The file is required to have a number on each line. If you wish to have another file format (how to file is build up), please provide how that is. Also, check out this page: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.